# How can I send a email between gmail accounts without giving out my IP address?

Tags: privacy, ip, gmail, geolocation

I would like to send an email from a gmail account to another gmail account, without giving out my IP address. I still would like to give out my name, so it is not completely anonymous, only without giving out my location.

I examined the header in an email sent from a gmail account to another gmail account in http://whatismyipaddress.com/trace-email, and the website shows the source location.

Is there some way to suppress the IP and thus location of the sender?

Comment: How about using a VPN?

Answer (score 5):

Gmail does not disclose your personal IP address when sending mail between two Gmail accounts (or Gmail to any other recipient).

The IP address in the headers is the IP address of the server which dispatched the email to the receiving SMTP server. In the case where you have a Gmail account, that is the Gmail servers IP address.

The only people who would know the IP address of the sender is Gmail themselves via their own logging.